# extra apostrophes string python

Tags: python, string

Whenever I replace one of the values in my array/list, the string that I try to replace it with gets extra apostrophes and or commas that I don't want. For example, I'm trying to assign index 2 of

```
guessHistory = ['','','','','','','','']
```

to the return value of this function:

```
def compareWords(word1, word2):
    result = 0
    if word1[0] == word2[0]:
        result +=1
    if word1[1] == word2[1]:
        result += 1
    if word1[2] == word2[2]:
        result += 1
    if word1[3] == word2[3]:
        result += 1
    if word1[4] == word2[4]:
        result += 1
    if word1[5] == word2[5]:
        result += 1
    print result, '/ 6 correct. \n'
    return result
```

I do this by

```
guessHistory[guessNum] = '[', compareWords(wordList[guessNum], password) , '/6 correct]'
```

and so i get this as a result
[image: example of text]

but id like it to be [3/6 correct] instead of ('[', 3, '/6 correct]')

```
guessHistoryIndex = 0
for index, item in enumerate(wordList, 1):
    print index, ' )', item, '   ' , guessHistory[guessHistoryIndex]
    guessHistoryIndex += 1
```

this is the loop that the index changes within

Comment: Please post enough code to actually reproduce the result (but no more).

Comment: Note that the code you do not show should use `string1 + string2` format. You need to show where this is done and how you print it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
guessHistory[guessNum] = '[', compareWords(wordList[guessNum], password) , '/6 correct]'
```

By using commas you're creating a tuple with several elements, and tuples look ugly when printed. You can combine the pieces together into a single string using `str.format`:

```
guessHistory[guessNum] = '[{0}/6 correct]'.format(compareWords(wordList[guessNum], password))
```

This will look much better.

Comment: thankyou you solved my problem, thanks everyone else who chipped in this was bugging me like crazy